# Bootstrap - align text and list in desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a text with a list like the picture

[image: 1]

for desktop/tablet view, but for mobile view I would display it in this way

[image: 2]

This is the way I'm trying to do that

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula ..../p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <p>More..</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any tips to make it better and more similar to the images?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like : https://jsfiddle.net/zoypggm2/1/

```
.more {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.more-mobile {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .more {
      display: none;
    }
    .more-mobile {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. ".hidden-xs" and ".hidden-sm" use to hide the element in respective screens. and ".visible-xs" and ".visible-sm" to show on respective screens.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-3 pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
   <p>More</p>
     <ul>
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
          <li>Link 3</li> 
        </ul>
   </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent magna tortor, tincidunt ac tristique sit amet, condimentum ut erat. Mauris sem mi, ultrices et hendrerit vitae, hendrerit non tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi eget leo lorem, ut placerat nisl. Aenean auctor volutpat condimentum. Morbi adipiscing leo et felis faucibus suscipit nec at odio. Pellentesque convallis turpis non sapien facilisis quis volutpat magna venenatis. Etiam nisi metus, imperdiet vitae lobortis sit amet, pharetra ut leo.</p>  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent magna tortor, tincidunt ac tristique sit amet, condimentum ut erat. Mauris sem mi, ultrices et hendrerit vitae, hendrerit non tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi eget leo lorem, ut placerat nisl. Aenean auctor volutpat condimentum. Morbi adipiscing leo et felis faucibus suscipit nec ase quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>

 <div class="col-md-3 visible-xs visible-sm">
 <p>More</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Link 1</li>
   <li>Link 2</li>
   <li>Link 3</li>
 </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```